# Save data and reset it every day in android

Tags: java, android, counter, store, reset

I need to store two counters and reset them to zero at midnight.
So far I have it stored as int : 
`public int wcounter=0;
    public int bcounter=0;`
that is incremented `wcounter++;` by an onclick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > I need to store two counters

You will want to use `SharedPreferences` to store these values. This will make sure they don't get deleted by the system. [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) have a good example to get you started on `ShredPreferences`.

2.

> and reset them to zero at midnight

For this part you will probably want to use an `AlarmManager`. You may even want to register a `BootReceiver` so if the device is restarted, your `AlarmManager` will still get triggered.

[AlarmManager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

[BroadcastReceiver Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

That should give you an idea of how to get started. You can find good examples and tutorials of each all over SO and The Google.

Comment: I manage to save the data with sharedpreferences but I can't find the proper way (on SO or the exmples) to set up the alarmmanager, can you help? thanks